# Exporting data to Peachtree using .net

Tags: .net

I need to export data from SQL server to PeachTree accounting software for this to accomplish I need .net based library, com based or another to connect to peachtree and export data into the peachtree company file, please help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing "[Dbeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/)" and connecting to database through of Dbeaver.
Then, export and import according of your necessity.
Lucky with that.